# How do I pass values to my parent controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am building a web application with AngularJS and am having trouble passing data from the child to parent view controller.

On page load I'm getting data from a service (e.g. username).

I would like to pass this value to my master page, but am currently unable to pass the value to my master page controller. For this reason, I'm requesting the data from my service two times (one in each page).

How can I share this value with the parent view?

Comment: so what did you try? insert some code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use $rootScope.yourVariable instead of $scope.yourVariable.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:**

Use `$emit` event to pass values from child to parent controllers. [Read docs for more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit).

**Case 2:**

Use `$broadcast` event to pass values from parent to child controllers. [Read docs for more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

```
 $socpe.$broadcast("Some Value", $scope.someVar);
```

and in other controller recieve it as:

```
$scope.$on("Some Value", function(event, value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

**Case 3:**

Use `$rootscope` to `$broadcast` event if controllers are siblings.

```
 $rootscope.$broadcast("Some Value", $scope.someVar);
```

and in other controller recieve it as:

```
$scope.$on("Some Value", function(event, value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

**Example:**

In the example I have used `$timeout` which will be replaced by your service call. Variable will be updated after 2 secs as mentioned in the timeout call.

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("ParentCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.parentVar = "This var belogs to ParentCtrl";
    $scope.childSharedValue = "Waiting for ChildCtrl to pass value";
    
    $scope.$on("Child Value", function(event, value){
      $scope.childSharedValue = value;
    });

    $timeout(function(){
       $scope.$broadcast("Parent Value", $scope.parentVar);
    }, 2000);
  })
  .controller("ChildCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.childVar = "This var belogs to ChildCtrl";
    $scope.parentSharedValue = "Waiting for ParentCtrl to pass value";
    
    $scope.$on("Parent Value", function(event, value){
      $scope.parentSharedValue = value;
    });

    $timeout(function(){
       $scope.$emit("Child Value", $scope.childVar);
    }, 2000);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  Parent Value: {{ parentVar}}<br />
  Child Shared Value: {{ childSharedValue }}<br /><br />
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
  Child Value: {{ childVar}}<br />
  Parent Shared Value: {{ parentSharedValue }}<br />
  </div>
</div>
```